# create upload script for google swiffy conversion

Tags: javascript, php, flash

I have a lot of .swf files (538 to be exact) that I want to convert to HTML5 using google swiffy, but they only allow one file at a time to upload and convert.

I can't use the adobe flash extension, since i don't have flash developer nor do i want to get it.

So I thought I might try to create a PHP or Javascript that would loop through all files and upload one-by-one and save the response from google swiffy. I used firebug extension in firefox to see what was being POSTED and where to. Of course, this is google we are talking about - one of the biggest organisations in the world so it probably is impossible to look at the source code for and try to work out how I can do what I want to do!

So basically, is it possible to create a script on a non-google server and send POST vars to "https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/upload"? (and hopefully get a response with swiffy code!)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only answer is to do it manually but use some sort mouse/keyboard control script, like http://autohotkey.com/ or as for me on slitaz linux is xdotool!